# Need shell_exec command to wait before it executes

Tags: php, shell, imagemagick, shell-exec

I'm currently having a problem with a shell command that is running before I want it to. For example I've got 6 commands that I all want to run in succession, and the first 5 are doing fine, but once I get to the last one, which relies on the output produced by the previous one, it won't run. In other words, is there anyway I can make my last command not run UNTIL the fifth one is fully completed? Here is a quick look at a snippet of my code for this situation.

```
        /*Renders user image*/
        //$command_1 = 'cd ./***/; povray +I'.$newname.' +O'.$newname_t.' +D '.$_POST['AA'].' +H75 +W100';
        $command_2 = 'cd ./***/; povray +I'.$newname.' +O'.$newname_i.' +D '.$_POST['AA'].' '.$_POST['resolution'];

        /*Command to copy the .pov, .ini, and .inc files from User_Files to the correct animation directory before frame renders can be done*/
        $command_cp_pov = 'cp ***'.$newname.' ***'.$location;
        $command_cp_ini = 'cp ***'.$newname_j.' ***'.$location;
        $command_cp_inc = 'cp *** ***'.$location;


        /*Render the frames for the animation*/
        $command_3 = 'cd ***'.$location.'; povray +I '.$newname_j.' +A +H384 +W512'.'> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';

        /*Testing purposes*/
        //echo $command_3."\n";

        /*Throw together the animation using the .png files in the directory*/
        $command_4 = 'cd ***'.$location.'; convert -delay 0 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif'.'> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';

        /*Testing purposes*/
        //echo $command_4;

        $shellOutput = shell_exec($command_2);
        $shellOutput = shell_exec($command_cp_pov);
        $shellOutput = shell_exec($command_cp_ini);
        $shellOutput = shell_exec($command_cp_inc);
        $shellOutput = shell_exec($command_3);
        // I want this command to run once the previous one is completely finished
        $shellOutput = shell_exec($command_4);
```

The 5th shell_exec command is running a .ini file using povray to create 50 frames of a scene so I can then use ImageMagick to put all of those frames together into a gif. It currently isn't working correctly though, because I need a way to somehow delay the execution of command_4 until command_3 is completely finished (all 50 frames are rendered).

If anyone is wondering what all of the asterisks('*') are, that is just me not feeling comfortable showing my actual locations within my server. Sorry if this confuses anyone.

Comment: you can check whether a process is running looking at its process id

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this result with PHP's [Process API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php).

If you look at the [proc_close](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-close.php) function you'll see it clearly states:

> proc_close() waits for the process to terminate, and returns its exit code.

There's a good example on the [proc_open manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php). During execution you can get status updates by calling [proc_get_status](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php).

Answer (score 0):

What would be the difference if you used exec instead and test the return variable for succes, then run the lastone

```
    /*Throw together the animation using the .png files in the directory*/

    /* can you change command to remain in the browser, 
       and report the results rather than writing to dev/null? */
    $command_3 = 'cd ***'.$location.'; povray +I '.$newname_j.' +A +H384 +W512'.'2>&1';


    exec($command_3,$shellOutput,$return_value);
    // I want this command to run once the previous one is completely finished
    if ($return_value === 0){
         $command_4 = 'cd ***'.$location.'; convert -delay 0 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif'.' 2>&1';

         exec($command_4,$shellOutput,$return_value);
         if ($return_value !== 0){
                $failed_result = "An error on 4 ($return) occured.<br>";
                foreach($shellOutput as $v)
                     echo "shelloutput: $v<br>";
         }
    } else {
         $failed_result = "An error on 3 ($return) occured.<br>";
         foreach($shellOutput as $v)
                   echo "shelloutput: $v<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix my problem. I did test it out, but still got the same results as before. I still get all 50 frames rendered, but the .gif just doesn't get created.

Comment: It's ok, later I think you can run them in the back. For now, it is needed to find out why it does not write the file though.

Comment: Correction...now the animation is still not being produced....I don't know why it worked once, and not again. I'm not seeing any echo's on my page with any shelloutput error messages.

Comment: If you have access to the apache log, it may be helpful to watch it while you run the script. `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log` for example.

Comment: Im going to try and gain access to the error log and if I do I'll watch it when I run the script to see what it shows. I'll report back with any new information.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the syntax of the shell you are using. But if this helps, I never had trouble with bash being so impatient as to start one command before povray finished the previous rendering in a huge batch.  I used syntax like this:

> bash
>
> for i in fracpos04*.pov; do povray $i +fn +w1280 +h960 +kff225 +a0.3; done